# Slicing a string to filter a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, datetime

Should be an easy one, just not getting anywhere with it after looking at any existing examples.

I'm trying to filter a df where a date/time in my df equals a date/time I have in another variable called "date".

Both of these are stored as strings.

The format of df['DATE'] is like this:

```
2017/11/28 14:19:58
```

The format of date is like this:

```
11/28/2017 14:19
```

I want these to return a match.

```
df = df[df['DATE'][:-3] == date]
```

Error I get is this:

```
raise IndexingError('Unalignable boolean Series provided as '
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided 
as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match
```

Seems like interpreter treats it as I am referencing the df position, not slicing the string within.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `pd.Series.str` accessor for slicing:

```
from datetime import datetime

s = pd.Series(['2016/09/25 12:29:18', '2017/11/28 14:19:58', '2018/01/02 03:35:12'])
date = '11/28/2017 14:19'

res = (s.str[:-3] == datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M'))

print(res)

0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thank you for your insight.  I needed to do a bit more manipulation, but a variation of this worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
df
    DATE
0   2017/11/21 14:19:58
1   2017/11/20 14:19:58
2   2017/11/21 12:19:58

date = '11/20/2017 14:19'

df[df['DATE'].apply(lambda x :pd.to_datetime(x,infer_datetime_format=True).strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'))==date]

    DATE
1   2017/11/20 14:19:58
```

You can convert either of them or both if you would like to do any other datetime based operations.